# Show when order number is unique for the item number

Tags: sql

[image]

I attached a simple table with two columns, Item number and Order number. In the example attached only item number **C5664** and **A9930** met the criteria.
How do I write this code in SQL?

Comment: could you please try something like SELECT A.ORDER_NUM FROM YOUR_TABLE AS A GROUP BY A.ORDER_NUM HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.ITEM_NUMBER)=1

Comment: @Sergey post your comment (without the alias) as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by the item numbers then the unique count for the order numbers will be 1

```
SELECT "Item Number", MAX("Order Number") AS "Order Number"
FROM yourtable AS t
GROUP BY "Item Number"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Order Number") = 1
```